# apache spark and scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
sqlContext.read.json("/home/mapr/nested_data.json")   

scala>val arr = udf(() => java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString())    
scala>val df2=df1.withColumn("UID",arr())
scala>df2.registerTempTable("nested_tbl")

scala>val contacts = df2.selectExpr("explode(contact) as e").select("e.ObjectId","e.name","e.phone","e.email","e.app_name","e.contact_add_person","e.source_app","e.campaigns","e.friend","e.Country","e.contact_id")

scala>val df3 = contacts.withColumn("CID",arr())
scala> df3.registerTempTable("contact_tbl")
scala> sqlContext.sql("select * from nested_tbl").show



+-------+----------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|Country|       DOB|     app_name|             contact|               email|              friend|                name|               phone|                 UID|
+-------+----------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  India|25/03/1995|        [IMT]|[[India,123,Wrapp...|[romaahire11@gmai...|[Kashmira G, Bhar...|[Roma Ahire, Roma A]|[9028512546, 7276...|c8736beb-347a-42d...|
|  India|22/05/1978|[IMT, ozmott]|[[India,595,Wrapp...|[azeem@yahoo.com,...|[Prjakta W, Praja...|[Azeem, Azeem Sha...|        [9785213564]|3acd01d2-6245-440...|
|  India|22/05/1978|[IMT, ozmott]|[[USA,789,Wrapped...|[praj@yahoo.com, ...|[Gouri Abhyankar,...|[Prajakta W, Praj...|        [9785213564]|a1b258eb-49b0-412...|
+-------+----------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+

scala> sqlContext.sql("select * from contact_tbl").show

+--------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+----------+---------+--------------------+-------+----------+--------------------+
|ObjectId|                name|               phone|    email|            app_name|contact_add_person|source_app|campaigns|              friend|Country|contact_id|                 CID|
+--------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+----------+---------+--------------------+-------+----------+--------------------+
|     123|[Gouri Abhyankar,...|[9845632158, 8963...|[gouri@yahoo.com,...|            [ozmott]|   NumberLong(100)|       ppm|       []|[Sakshi D, Roma A...|  India|       102|675662fa-2923-477...|
|     59b|[Sakshi D, Sakshi...|        [9478321564]|[sakshid@yahoo.co...|[ozmott, ppm, fac...|   NumberLong(100)|       abc| [c1, c2]|[Gouri Abhyankar,...|    USA|       105|350b3c5a-9481-465...|
|     fff|[Prajakta Walimbe...|[9478321564, 8547...|[praj@yahoo.com, ...|       [ozmott, ppm]|   NumberLong(100)|       abc| [c1, c2]|             [Azeem]|  India|       102|dfa527a5-b2e1-418...|
|     ecb|[Azeem, Azeem Sha...|        [9785213564]|[azeem@yahoo.com,...|[ozmott, ppm, fac...|   NumberLong(100)|       abc| [c1, c2]|[Azeem, Tejashree...|  India|       105|3a2475a1-16e6-475...|
|     595|[Roma Ahire, Roma A]|        [7276373611]|[romaahire11@gmai...|               [IMT]|   NumberLong(100)|          |       []|[Sakshi D, Tejash...|  India|       102|feea8973-75c9-410...|
|     59b|[Sakshi D, Sakshi...|        [9478321564]|[sakshid@yahoo.co...|[ozmott, ppm, fac...|   NumberLong(100)|       abc| [c1, c2]|[Gouri Abhyankar,...|    USA|       105|50e09968-0265-415...|
|     fff|[Prajakta Walimbe...|[9478321564, 8547...|[praj@yahoo.com, ...|       [ozmott, ppm]|   NumberLong(100)|       abc| [c1, c2]|             [Azeem]|  India|       102|ecd559ef-7ad1-49c...|
|     ecb|[Azeem, Azeem Sha...|        [9785213564]|[azeem@yahoo.com,...|[ozmott, ppm, fac...|   NumberLong(100)|       abc| [c1, c2]|[Azeem, Tejashree...|  India|       105|521ad147-73fb-4a9...|
|     789|[Sakshi D, Sakshi...|        [9478321564]|[sakshid@yahoo.co...|[ozmott, ppm, fac...|   NumberLong(100)|       abc| [c1, c2]|[Gouri Abhyankar,...|    USA|       105|874cd6d0-8bba-46c...|
|     ecb|[Azeem, Azeem Sha...|        [9785213564]|[azeem@yahoo.com,...|[ozmott, ppm, fac...|   NumberLong(100)|       abc| [c1, c2]|[Azeem, Tejashree...|  India|       105|47577ef6-1faa-4ba...|
+--------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+----------+---------+--------------------+-------+----------+--------------------+
```

I'm creating a table by reading a JSON file, registering it as a temporary table in Spark and then writing it to Hive. I have the following question(s) regarding the process :

1) When I intake another file in spark, I want to check if `email` is already present. If yes, then update the record, otherwise insert it as a new record.

2) Another question is from main table(nested_tbl) contact is struct Type column which I have taken as another registerTempTable. If the name from main table is present in contact table's friend column then I want to append id's of that name column(first table) in the new table (contact_tbl).

For eg. in front of name ( Gouri Abhyankar )in contact table there should be UID(in a column naming UID's) of Prajakta Walimbe from nested_tbl as Gouri Abhyankar is friend of Prajakta as seen in nested_tbl. And such for other rows too

Comment: also the name and friend columns are Array<String> so i am facing the problem to trace each row and map id's according to that

Comment: Please read [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: sample json file would be help you to get solution quickly